# How to get total of columns in SSRS or report builder where Top 10 was applied to them

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder, powerbi-paginated-reports

I am trying to get a Total column per business unit, I can't use the Add total option because it sums all the data in the dataset and my table only displays top 10 cities, is there a way I can get the total for top 10 cities?

[image]

When trying to add the total as column I get full total of all cities not only the top 10 or 12
[image]

Comment: Looks like a matrix, it should be fairly staright forward to just add a total for each business unit. Show us your design view of this report please

Comment: Hi Harry, when I add the total column it gives me the total of all cities instead of just the top 12 or top 10 (I added a pic of that to my original post). I also tried creating a column
=IIF(Fields!Ranking.Value<=12 AND Fields!Dim__Country_.Value="United States", Fields!I_Total_United_States_.Value,0)
then  a measure that sums that column, but for some reason I don't get the right numbers

Comment: How are you filtering the top 10. Are you doing this in your dataset query or in the dataset filters or in the tablix ?